# how to Change Session.ToString to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("module", "CallLogDetail");
HttpContext.Session.SetString("module", "CommentsPanel");
HttpContext.Session.SetString("module", "Update");
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", "0");
       
return View();
```

i have these code of line here Id is string how can i now change it to int.

Comment: Do you wanna set id in int? HttpContext.Session.SetInt32 ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set Id to `int` instead of `string` in session, You can use `.SetInt32(string key,int value)` to achieve it.

Please refer to this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `GetInt32(String key)`. to get it back out as an int.